# Django REST Upload CSV return Response with All posts

Tags: python, django, csv

I have a Blog CMS that's working great, but I want to be able to upload a CSV with multiple test posts, and then add them to the database all at once. Right now I can upload the CSV and iterate through the lines, but because my POST functions returns a Response, it quits after one iteration. How can I get it to iterate through all the lines and then return the list of created Blog Posts?

Here is my code that works to create one at a time:

```
class PostsImportAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class    = DashboardPostSerializer
    permission_classes  = [IsOwner]
    pagination_class    = BlogPostPagination

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return BlogPost.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.FILES:
            data = request.data
        else:
            data = request.data.copy()

        csv_file = TextIOWrapper(data['csv'].file, encoding='ascii', errors='replace')
        import_csv = csv.reader(csv_file)
        next(import_csv)
        counter = 0
        for line in import_csv:
            if line:
                data['title'] = line[0]
                data['body'] = line[1]
                date_field  = line[2].split('+')
                data['created_at']  = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_field[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                data['published'] = line[3]

                serializer  = DashboardPostImportSerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})
                if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    serializer.save()
                    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
                return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

This works greater for one at a time, but what I'd like to do is increment my counter for each completed row, then return a queryset of posts that match the length of the counter. But since returning my Response breaks the loop, I'm not sure the best next step.

Comment: The solution is to move the response out of the loop - iterate through all the lines, keeping track of the fails and once you finish with the loop return a response

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to kiwibg, this is the working code. It iterates through the csv and creates all the posts, although the final serializer only returns the last post created. But for the purposes intended, this is good enough.

```
class PostsImportAPIView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class    = DashboardPostSerializer
    permission_classes  = [IsOwner]
    pagination_class    = BlogPostPagination

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return BlogPost.objects.all()

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.FILES:
            data = request.data
        else:
            data = request.data.copy()

        csv_file = TextIOWrapper(data['csv'].file, encoding='ascii', errors='replace')
        import_csv = csv.reader(csv_file)
        next(import_csv)
        counter = 0
        for line in import_csv:
            if line:
                data['title'] = line[0]
                data['body'] = line[1]
                date_field  = line[2].split('+')
                data['created_at']  = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_field[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
                data['published'] = line[3]

                serializer  = DashboardPostImportSerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})
                if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    counter += 1
                    serializer.save()

        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```